# Можно ли оптимизировать проверку строки?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте.
Есть строка, счет теннисного матча. Она может иметь следующие значения:
"15:15","30:0","0:30","1:1","2:0","0:2".
Я по-колхозному создаю паттерн:

```
private static final String THIRD_POINT_PATTERN = "(^@?15:15@?$)|(^@?30:0@?$)|(^@?0:30@?$)|(^@?2:0@?$)|(^@?0:2@?$)|(^@?1:1@?$)";
```

и проверяю строковую переменную pointThree на соответствие этому паттерну:

```
Pattern pExpectedScore = Pattern.compile(THIRD_POINT_PATTERN);
if (!pExpectedScore.matcher(pointThree).find()) {
            return false;
        }
```

Можно ли это делать без написания такого длинного патерна?

Comment: а куда делись 40? почему макс 2?

Comment: Это третье очко гейма. Меня пугает паттрен шестого :-)

Comment: в гейме макс 40 поинтов, а вот кол-во геймов вроде неограничено. К сожалению в этих тонкостях я уже не особо.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Первое, что приходит в голову - это записать просто и понятно

```
^(15:15|30:0|0:30|1:1|2:0|0:2)$
```

дальше можно немного пожать нолики, правда, короче выражение от этого не станет:

```
^(15:15|(30|2):0|0:(30|2)|1:1)$
```

И ещё можно обратить внимание на `15:15` и `1:1`:

```
^((15?):\2|(30|2):0|0:(30|2)$
```

Можно пошаманить с симметричностью, но оно только более мутным станет:

```
^((15?):\2|(?=\d+:\d+$)(0:)?(30|2)(:0)?)$
```

И можно общий формат оттащить в начало:

```
^(?=\d+:\d+$)((15?):\2|(0:)?(30|2)(:0)?)$
```

На этом у меня идеи закончились.

**PS: Мне тут самый первый вариант больше всего нравится.**

Comment: может без регулярок, используя массив?

Comment: ну ты ж сам хотел регулярку?

Comment: не принципиально, лишь бы покороче и поэлегантнее. А то дальше паттерн может вырасти совсем до неприличных размеров.

Comment: дописал ещё что-то - может пригодится. с массивом мне лень делать. и вообще, тогда уж со словарём.

Comment: @Qwertiy словарь (хэш-таблица же?) для 6 значений может не дать пользы вообще - для новых строк нужно будет хэш считать, да и String#compare() и так быстро работает, тем более на строках длиной в 5 символов. Поддерживаю вариант с массивом и первую вашу регулярку, выбрал бы любой вариант из двух по настроению.

Answer (score 2):

Учитывая, что строки просто проверяются на совпадение, можно хранить их в множестве.

```
Set<String> validScores = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("15:15","30:0","0:30","1:1","2:0","0:2"));
```

затем искать строку в множестве:

```
boolean isValidScore(String score) {
    return validScores.contains(score);
}
```

для гибкости, в дальнейшем можно считывать список допустимых счетов из файла или БД.

Answer (score 1):

**Как вариант:**

```
(3?0|15):(3?0|15)|[0-2]:[0-2]
```

**Если вспомнить теннис, где есть ещё 40 поинтов и 6 геймов, то как-то так:**

```
([34]?0|15):([34]?0|15)|[0-6]:[0-6]
```

P.S. Но, как верно намекнул Qwertiy: чем проще регулярка читается, тем приятнее ))

Comment: `[0-2]:[0-2]` - пропустит всякие 0:1 и 1:2, что, вроде, вопросу не соответствует... Да и про 0:15 и 30:15 там как-то нет...

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, чот сначала написал общую регулярку, потом сократил с учетом макс 2 и без 40 и не перепроверил, что удовлетворяет условиям задачи.